# MySQL SUBSTR function with Join and IF conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, substr

I'll try to be as clear as possible to see if I can express my problem.

I have table A and B. Both have a field named cod(int), but in table B the cod have a digit that variates according to cod number.

Exemple:

Table A
cod=12345

Table B
cod=123459

OR

Table A
cod=1234

Table B
cod=12349

I tried to use the follow query:

```
SELECT a.cod, a.qtd, a.vlr, a.status, b.desc
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN tableB b ON SUBSTR(b.cod,1,LENGTH(a.cod))=a.cod
WHERE a.coddistrib=2544 AND a.nrolote=41862 AND a.nropedido=5 
GROUP BY a.cod
```

The problem is the cod length can be 4 or 5 without the digit. So the two statements below are true:

SUBSTR(123456,1,5)=12345

SUBSTR(123456,1,4)=1234

I thought about something like IF(LENGTH(b.cod) = LENGTH(a.cod)+1, ) but I don´t how can this work inside the query.

any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.cod, b.cod codb
FROM
    A INNER JOIN 
    B ON LENGTH(a.cod) + 1 = LENGTH(b.cod) AND 
         SUBSTR(b.cod,1,LENGTH(a.cod)) = a.cod
```

Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c26b/1

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SUBSTR(b.cod,1,substr(a.cod,1,instr(a.cod,',')))
```

Depending on the digit sign change `','` for `'.'`